# using(DataTable dt =new DataTable() shows an error

Tags: c#

This is what am trying to do but in the line using
`(DataTable dt= new DataTable())` the 'using' gives an error which states

> 'DataTable': type used in a using statement must be implicitly
>   convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

```
 private void  BindGrid()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["laundarycon"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from item"))
            {
                using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                   using( DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            da.Fill(dt);
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView2.DataBind();

                        }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I had the same problem before. Did you class implements the `System.IDisposable` interface?

Comment: `DataTable` does not implement `IDisposable` this is what the error is saying, you cannot use using `using` block with types that do not inherit from `IDisposable`

Answer (score 0):

No need of using, just try this,

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable()
```

**Explanation:**

DataTable don't actually have any unmanaged resources, As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and instantiate it in a using statement.

Comment: add explanation why `using` cannot be used

Answer (score 0):

Add the reference of Datatable by

```
using System.Data;
```

in first couple of line

and removing the `using( DataTable dt = new DataTable())` code 
just use

DataTable dt = new DataTable()
    this portion will be like that

```
using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);                      
                    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView2.DataBind();

                }
```